# Why compiler point to global variable using [rip+0x00]

Tags: c, compilation, x86-64, object-files, relocation

I am new to compiler, and I am trying to understand why the compiler emit this code. I have this very simple C code

```c
// main.c
int b = 7;

int main(){
    int a = 5 + b;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using gcc 13.2 by running

```bash
gcc -g -c -o main.o main.c
```

I inspect the code by running

```bash
objdump -M intel -d main.o
```

And this is the result that I get

```bash
main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   55                      push   rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # e <main+0xe>
   e:   83 c0 05                add    eax,0x5
  11:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
  14:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  19:   5d                      pop    rbp
  1a:   c3                      ret
```

What I don't understand is the line 8 `mov eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]` . From what I can understand, `rip` register is the instruction pointer and will [point to the next instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429026/understanding-how-eip-rip-register-works). This means the code try to load the value at the address `[rip+0x0]`, which is the next instruction? But the next instruction is not the value we want?

I am aware that this is the compiled file and when linking happens these addresses can change (I did link the file `gcc -o final main.o`) and the address after linking actually makes sense (it points to somewhere else - I presume the `.data` section that contains the actual value). However, I don't understand the code in the compiled file

I include the file in this [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/86vdo8esz). In the default view the code is ok, but if you turn on the option "Link to Binary" in the "Output" options with `-c` as a compiler option, you'' see the same output as `objdump`.  Without `-c`, you'll see a sensible address from the actual linked executable, or with "compile to binary object" you'll see the same [RIP+0] but with an extra line showing stuff about the symbol name it's supposed to reference.

**EDIT**: I tried the suggestion by @Peter Cordes and still get the same result. I tried with another example that I think can demonstrate my point better

```c
int b = 7;
int c = 3;

int main(){
    int a = 5 + b;
    int d = 6 + c;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the disassembled file through `gcc -c` and `objdump -drwC -Mintel`

```bash
main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   55                      push   rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # e <main+0xe>    a: R_X86_64_PC32     b-0x4
   e:   83 c0 05                add    eax,0x5
  11:   89 45 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  14:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # 1a <main+0x1a>  16: R_X86_64_PC32    c-0x4
  1a:   83 c0 06                add    eax,0x6
  1d:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
  20:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  25:   5d                      pop    rbp
  26:   c3                      ret
```

As you can see, both global variables somehow are pointed by the "same" address `[rip+0x0]`, which is not clear to me why this is the case and what does this `[rip+0x0]` mean

Comment: You disassembled `.o` (unlinked object file) and forgot to use `-r` to show relocation entries for the placeholders.  Use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  Or look at GCC's asm output, or disassemble a linked binary.  (You broke Godbolt's "link to binary" option by including `-c` in the command line textbox, so it still actually only made an object file.  https://godbolt.org/z/xsGMsoTYd shows disassembly of a linked executable.)

Comment: This has come up frequently in previous questions, but I'm not immediately finding an exact duplicate.  [dissassemble .o file with fixups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31270259) mentions something similar but only answered in comments.

Comment: @coreds I tried your option `-drwC` and still get the same result. Also, I am interested in the compiled result and not the linked result, as the linked result actually show the correct relocation. My question is more of, why does the code show `rip+0x00` and how does the linker know which global variable we means in the code

Comment: The disassembler shows 0 for the offset because that's the value in the object file. The actual value isn't there because it will be filled in by the linker. The linker knows what to put because of the relocation information, which is printed by objdump when you use the -r option, as suggested by Peter.

Comment: @prl I am still a little bit confused here. If what you say is correct, then how can the linker know which one is `b` and which one is `c` for it to link, when both are referred to as ` [rip+0x0]` (line 8 and 14)

Comment: As I wrote, **The linker knows what to put because of the relocation information**. The value in the offset field of the instruction is not what the linker uses to determine what to put there.

Comment: Your example output would be clearer if you used variable names that weren't also hex digits, so the `objdump -dr` comments showing the relocation info would be more distinct from the computed addresses based on the placeholder `rel32=0`.

Comment: Also, `[rip+0x0]` is the same addressing *mode*, but when used at two different locations would be two different (absolute) addresses, since the RIP value would be different at run-time for each instance.  (If you actually ran this un-linked object file, which you couldn't normally.)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289761/2554472) nicely illustrates what the linker does for some relocation types (though not for PC32).